# VLC from menu or double-click starts in background, terminates

Tags: gnome, vlc, background-process

On most Ubunutus, VLC can be started from the gnome launcher(?) or by double-clicking on assiociated items in nemo or nautilus. I expect VLC to run; in the second case, I expect the file I clicked on to be played back.

Since yesterday, this is no longer the case. Mostly, nothing visible happens. In very rare cases of clicking on files, a control-less version of vlc (like cvlc) appears, playing the file, but closes after a few seconds. I cannot reproduce when this happens, and there is never a visible window when choosing vlc from the launcher.

Things I have found/tried so far:

- starting programs by double-clicking still works for everything else.
- starting `vlc` from a terminal works, as does `vlc --started-from-file <filename>`: playback with controls, does not terminate after a few seconds.
- `vlc --reset-config` did not help, neither did deleting `~/.config/vlc`
- `/usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop` exists in its packaged state; deleting it caused VLC to disappear from the launcher, showing it was being read. `apt --reinstall`ing vlc restored the file, but did not help.
- for a few seconds after running vlc from menu/double-click, a `/usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file <filename>` process is running. Unfortunately, it is `Sl`, not `Sl+`, explaining why I cannot see or hear it.
- When a VLC instance was started from the console, double-clicking on a media file in nemo/nautilus causes that VLC instance to play back the file.

I am using a gnome-flavored and up-to-date ubuntu 15.10, currently on 4.2.0-25-generic, 64 bit. I am not aware of any changes I made to the system during the time this behavior appeared.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a `vlc.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: Good point, but no, that does not exist. I've updated the question to indicate that the global `.desktop` file appears to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the already runnig vlc process (with no window displayed). Then try clicking the icon again.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1276503/1128608